# Hosting a Server on a CentOS Virtual Machine - Bridged Connection?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vmware, centos-6

I have a Virtual Machine (VMWare) running CentOS 6.7.  I am looking to host a [Shiny Server for R](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/), with which I am deploying a Web Application on my corporate network.

I think that I need a `Static IP` on my `Virtual Machine` and I believe that I need to configure my network connection as a `bridged adapter`.

I have Googled around a bit, and I believe that I have an idea about how to do this, but I have a couple of questions for this process:

- In the VMWare Settings, I can create a `bridged connection`, like in this photo:
  [Image of the VMWare settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRvzS.png).  Is this the only configuration that I need to do?
- Or do I need to go into the terminal and follow the set of instructions described on this website: banym.de/linux/centos/setup-bridge-device-on-centos (I can't post more than two links, sorry!)
- Since I need a static IP address, I would think that I need to go into the terminal and follow the instructions to turn the `Network Manager off`, `Create br0 configuration`, `Modify eth0 configuration` and then `restart the network`.
- Or do I just need to configure it on the VMWare Settings and then modify eth0 inside of the guest virtual box?

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you :)

**Update:**
Here is what my `eth0` currently looks like:

```
EVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
ETHTOOL_OPTS="autoneg off speed 100 duplex full"
BRIDGE=br0
HWADDR=00:0C:29:CD:EB:7F
```

Do I need to add:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=my_static_IP
NETMASK=my_network_mask
```

Where do I get my network mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Insofar as VB is concerned, this is all you need to do.
2. No, this is not necessary: this is the actual operation of bridging two interfaces, which is carried out by VB for you.
3. Once again, this is not necessary, because the whole paraphernalia of the bridge are taken care of by VB.
4. This is correct: after making the correct choice in step 1, inside your VM all you have to do is configure `eth0` to have a static IP address.

From the user point of view, after choosing the setting `bridged adapter`, the bridge requires no further operation. Indeed, if you were satisfied with a DHCP address, there would be **nothing else to do**, full stop. Since instead you require (quite understandably) a fixed IP address, you must just configure your interface `eth0` for this, instead for requesting any IP address via DHCP.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  One more question.  My `ifcfg-eth0` currently looks like what I've got in the Update.  Do I need to add the other items (that I left blank).  See above.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Yes you do. You must setup a static IP address.

Comment: Does the `Static IP Address` need to be different than the `IPv4 Address` that I find using `ipconfig` on my Windows side?

Comment: @Nick Yes it does. It must differ from the IP addresses of all the others pcs on your network, otherwise you will get some very strange errors. It must also belong to the same `broadcast address`. For instance,  if your network is 192.168.0.xxx (most home networks are either this or 192.168.1.xxx), then the static IP also must be of the kind 192.168.0.xxx (or 192.168.1.xxx, whichever applies). If you need to find out the IP addresses of other pcs on your LAN, search Google for **nmap for Windows**.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  See, my IT team asked for a "`subnet`", so I provided to them my `subnet mask` and my host `IPv4 Address`.  They turned the host `IPv4` address into a static IP address (which I didn't want).  The problem is, I am trying to get a Static IP address, but I'm not sure what the IP address would even be for me to give them (to turn into a static one).  What should I tell them?  Where do I find an IP address to give them?

Comment: @Nick tell them you want this subnet: if they gave you, for your PC, for instance, 192.168.1.7, choose the largest number divisible by four which is smaller than this (in this case, 192.168.1.4), then tell them you want the subnet **192.168.1.4/30**.  Then the numbers 192.168.1.4-192.168.1.7 are yours. Use 192.168.1.7 for the Windows pc, and 192.168.1.6 for your Linux host.

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  What is the `/30`?

Comment: @Nick /30 identifies the subnet: it means the first 30 bits remain the same, the remaining 2 bits are free to vary. In the example above,  192.168.1.4/30 means *all numebrs from 192.168.1.4 to 192.168.1.7*.

Comment: Hi, I continued my question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1001501/configuring-my-bridged-network-on-a-centos-virtual-machine