# Configuring my Bridged Network on a CentOS Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I am having trouble configuring my Bridged Network Connection on my CentOS 6.7 Virtual Machine.  I am trying to run a `R Shiny-Server` Web Application on this Virtual Machine.  When I try to go to :3838, I receive a timeout error.

I have received a `Static IP Address` from my IT Department.

Here are the steps that I've taken so far:

1. [Setting up a Bridged Connection][1]
2. I ran `ifconfig -a` in my terminal and received this:

Output:

```
bridge0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:6F:AF:DD:10:D2  
          inet6 addr: fe80::806f:afff:fedd:10d2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:2862 (2.7 KiB)

br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fecd:eb7f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:76 (76.0 b)  TX bytes:258 (258.0 b)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:CD:EB:7F  
          inet addr:<some_ip_addr_here>  Bcast:<broadcast_address>  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fecd:eb7f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10890823 (10.3 MiB)  TX bytes:3601 (3.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)
```

I'm not sure what `bridge0` is... I think I created it a while ago when I was trying to configure the network.

3. I then edited `ifcnfg eth0` to the following:

[image]

4. My `ipconfig` is here:

Output:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : <host_IP_addr_here>
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : <host_default_gateway>
```

Any help is appreciated to help me properly set up my bridged connection!

**Update:**
My `network-scripts` looks like the following:

[image]

My network is currently connected to `Auto-eth0` and not `eth0`

**Update 2:**
My `ip route show` is as follows.  The 10.18.81.251 is the correct `Static IP` address.

```
10.18.81.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.18.81.251  metric 1
```

Comment: When I run `ifcfg-eth0`, I see an IP address that isn't either the host nor the static IP address.  I can ping this address successfully.  I can also ping the host from the Virtual Machine.  But when I try to ping the Static IP Address from the host, I receive `<host_ip>: Destination Host Unreachable`.

Comment: I added an update.  In the VM, I am connected to Auto-eth0, and in `network-scripts`, I am editing `eth0`.  Should I be editing `Auto-eth0`?  I am not sure what `br0` and `ifcfg-Bridge-Connection1` are... I think I manually created those before I was troubleshooting.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, I edited Auto-eth0 with the same revisions as `eth0`, and I can now ping my Static IP from the host PC.  It's weird though.  I can ping successfully to the IP address, but the connection times out when I try to access the <static_ip>:3838 from another host.  On the VM, running `localhost:3838` successfully displays the web app.  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated it in Update 2.

Comment: `localhost;3838` displays properly, but when I run `10.18.81.251:3838` it tells me that it is `Unable to Find the Proxy Server`

Comment: Pls see my answer, after that let me know.

Comment: Virtualbox networking by default is nat you need bridged. Did you configure that already? (under vm settings - network)

Comment: @badge-be, Yes, I did indeed configure it.